# Button's clickable area is above the button

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm relitavely new to HTML and have ran into this error after using display: flex.
My buttons clickable area is about 10px above the actual button, and when I use inspect element, the button highlight says its above where the visible button is.

```html
<body>
    <h1 id="HomepageTitle" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; font-family: sans-serif; color: black;">CoderTom</h1>
    <h2 id="HomepageHeader" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; font-family: sans-serif; color: blue;">Home</h3>

    <div class="button-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        <a href="contactpage.html"><button style="position : relative; top: 50px; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 55); font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 700; color: black; width: 100%; height: 100%;">Contact</button></a>
    </div>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post it in a codesandbox ? Also please attach a image of what you got.

Answer (score 1):

property top: 50px in anchor tag moves element up 50px. I guess you wanted to give it to parent (.button-group)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to style the  tag like a button and add ' display: block '
Also remember to reset default styling of the browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).